# Run multiple scripts and continue until every script is done

Tags: shell-script, parallelism

my question is, can I run multiple scripts at once. I have access to a cluster with 32 cpus but at the same time I have 900 scripts. Now what I would like to do is, put every script in a queue, and once a script is done start another one. I am not trying to do a simple loop, since I want all (or almost all) cpus running in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for something like the [GNU Parallel utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Here's an excerpt from its description:

> For each line of input GNU parallel will execute command with the line as arguments. If no command is given, the line of input is executed. Several lines will be run in parallel.

In your case, you would limit yourself to 32 concurrent scripts with something like the following:

```
parallel -j32 ::: ./script1 ./script2 (...) ./script900
```

Or you could make `parallel` read the script names from a file, or if all the runs are instances of the same script, store just the parameters in an input file, etc.; read the documentation for many possible variations.

Comment: If your cluster has more than one machine (e.g. 4 machines with 8 cores) use '-S server1,server2,server3,server4'.

Comment: This parallel script was perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you kick of all the scripts in the directory using:

```
for FILE in *.sh; do ./$FILE & done;
```

And let the process scheduler do it's work.

Comment: I tried using it this way, but the problem was that it ran everything! at the same time.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Everything runs in parallel...